# How to get the windows system boot time using php code

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to fetch the booting time from the windows system using php code? I am doing a project and the requirement is to calculate the time from the system boot time to log off time. As I am new for developing I have no idea of how to fetch the boot time using php and store in mysql. I knew we can find it manually by giving the `systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"` in windows7 command prompt. But is it possible grammatically using php?. I have searched for the possibilities but I get only for Linux OS. Can anyone help me in this issue? I am from testing background and new for developing.I need help.

Comment: You need the values for the Server or the Client?

Comment: @sujit Agarwal I need values for Client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy/paste this:

```
<?php
$info = exec('systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"');
echo $info;
?>
```

If you need only date:

```
<?php
$info = exec('systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"');
echo trim(str_replace("System Boot Time:", "", $info));
?>
```

Comment: The Above code displays the server boot time. I need to find the boot time from the client machine